# change of date format in awk command

Tags: shell-script, awk, date, text-formatting

I have a file mdn.txt with following sample record.

mdn.txt:

```
123456,2711448,1,20150214092425,20150714092425,120,20150814163821,,123,,,123,20150214092425,,123,,,123,20150214092425,,123,Y
```

Now I want to process every record of my file by `awk` and want to change the format of date field like below:

```
123456,2711448,1,14-02-2015 09:24:25,14-07-2015 09:24:25,120,14-08-2015 16:38:21,,123,,,123,14-02-2015 09:24:25,,123,,,123,14-02-2015 09:24:25,,123,Y
```

Date input hereby is digits with (**Y**ear,**M**onth,**D**ay,**H**our,**M**inute,**S**econd)

```
YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
```

Output should be:

```
DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

Comment: Are the columns always the same, or do you need to replace any 14-digit strings into a date. If the columns are fixed, please state which fields (index numbers) contain dates to make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," 
            n=split("4,5,7,13,19", f)   # array of input field numbers
     }
     { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) if($f[i]) $f[i] = dconv($f[i]); print 
     }
     function dconv(x) {
       YY=substr(x, 1, 4)
       mm=substr(x, 5, 2)
       dd=substr(x, 7, 2)
       hh=substr(x, 9, 2)
       nn=substr(x,11, 2)
       ss=substr(x,13, 2)
       return dd"-"mm"-"YY" "hh":"nn":"ss  
     }' file
```

---

Below, is (fundamentally) the same script, with one more array (and without the function)

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","
            nf=split("4,5,7,13,19", f)                           # array of input field numbers
            nd=split(",7,2,-,5,2,-,1,4, ,9,2,:,11,2,:,13,2", d)  # array of date subfield info (in output order): prefix(out),pos(in),len(in)         
     }
     { for(i=1; i<=nf; i++){ 
           if($f[i]) {
               fmod=""
               for(j=1; j<=nd; j+=3) fmod=fmod sprintf("%s", d[j] substr($f[i], d[j+1], d[j+2]))
               $f[i] = fmod
           }
       } print
     }' file
```

Comment: a variation for defining the function with `gensub`:  `function dconv(x) { x = gensub(/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/,"\\3-\\2-\\1 \\4:\\5:\\6",1,x) ; return x }`

Comment: `gensub` is an [extensions in `gawk` (GNU awk)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/POSIX_002fGNU.html), but is *not* in POSIX awk

Comment: if suppose any date field comes blank then below output comes by this command.which need to be handle. please suggest further. 123456,2711448,1,14-02-2015 09:24:25,14-07-2015 09:24:25,120,-- ::,,123,,,123,14-02-2015 09:24:25,,123,,,123,14-02-2015 09:24:25,,123,Y

Comment: The answer has been updated with a condition test for empty date fields. It now leave the field empty (as per the input)

Answer (score 1):

Next will convert any field of 14 digits:

```
awk -F, ' function form(E){
              $E=substr($E,1,4) "-" substr($E,5,2) "-" substr($E,7,2) " "\
                 substr($E,9,2) ":" substr($E,11,2) ":" substr($E,13)
        }
        { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
              if($i ~ /[0-9]{14}/)
                  form(i)
          print
        }' OFS=, mdn.txt
```

Comment: i am getting the same output as input. the output is coming as below.123456,2711448,1,20150214092425,20150714092425,120,20150814163821,,123,,,123,20150214092425,,123,,,123,20150214092425,,123,Y

Comment: @user3548033 I have tried your string — all dates are successfully converted.

Answer (score -1):

If the source string is held in variable s, then you could just use printf and substr ie

printf("%2d-%2d-%4d %2d:%2d:%2d", substr(s,7,2), substr(s,5,2), substr(s,1,4), substr(s,9,2), substr(s,11,2), substr(s,13,2) )